# Out Of Order commits mechanism for Reactor Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor, reactor-kafka

I recently saw the Spring-Kafka project has implemented [OOO commits for processing Kafka messages](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#ooo-commits). I wonder how this feature can be used or implemented with Reactor-Kafka. Without this, it will potentially cause us to commit a previous message that its processing hasn't been completed.

The solution we seek is to track the polled messages and to commit a message only after all of the previous messages (in the same partition) have been acknowledged.

I've also seen some talks about the subject on other frameworks. As said it has been implemented in Spring-Kafka. More to this, there's a great article for explaining Quarkus' implementation for this very issue. [Right here](https://quarkus.io/blog/kafka-commit-strategies/#the-throttled-strategy). It would really help me to know of any solution for this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

from Reactor Kafka Reference docs

> Starting with version 1.3.8, commits can be performed out of order and
> the framework will defer the commits as needed, until any "gaps" are
> filled. This removes the need for applications to keep track of
> offsets and commit them in the right order.

there was an [issue](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-kafka/pull/260) in the original implementation related to rebalance that has been fixed in 1.3.10